# How do the skills actually work?

Tags: resident-evil-6

*RE6*'s skills list doesn't do a very good job of explaining how exactly equipping skills affects gameplay. I have invested in "Defense" but I've read that it only reduces gun damage (not all damage). Is this true? Either way, how much is damage reduced? Are regular zombie bites reduced by half? Something else? Does "Melee" increase kicking power or just knife power, and by how much? How much is Firearm "power increased"?

How are the gains of all of the skills quantified, and do any of their effects differ from the obvious interpretation of their listed descriptions? There are 26 identified and 17 unidentified skills.

[image: skills list]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a full list of [all skills here](https://web.archive.org/web/20121008214751/http://www.chaoshour.com/articles/feature/resident-evil-6-game-guide-skills-agent-hunt-mercenaries-good-cost-where-to-get). Which appear to have much better description include actual percentage values.

This list also says that melee skill increase weapons such as knife and stun rod (not mentioning kicking power) but I assume does include Jake's hand-to-hand combat 'weapon'. It also hints that "Defense" includes all damage, not just from firearms.

I didn't create this list so I don't know where these values came from, but the seem pretty logical to me.